# Using PLINQ causing OutofMemory Exception but not with LINQ?

Tags: c#, plinq

I have come across the scenario, where using LINQ is working fine, but PLINQ causing "OutOfMemoryException". Following is the sample code

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

        var guidList = new List<Guid>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            guidList.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
        }
       timer.Start();

        // var groupedList = guidList.GroupBy(f => f).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
        var groupedList = guidList.AsParallel().GroupBy(f => f).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
        timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Took {0} ms time with result: {1} duplications", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, groupedList.Count()));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Throwing inner exception "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown"..what could be the issue? What is the guidelines to use PLINQ for this type of scenario, Thanks in advance.

Comment: GroupBy isn't a good choice to do in parallel. Try moving that after the group by and see if that fixes the issue. The where is easy to do in parallel.

Comment: I am going to guess the reason you are getting this expection is because you are trying to allocate 160,000,000 bytes into memory. ( A GUID is 128-bits i.e. 16 bytes ). I think that would break down to about 16GB if I am not mistaken. When you use a non-parallel approach, does the code actually finish, allocation of that much memory should also fail.

Comment: You are doing everything on a 64-bit operating system right?

Comment: Ramhound, Thanks for taking time to look over, i am using 32-bit OS, dual core, with 2GB RAM. This works fine with  non-parallel approach.

Comment: Rangoric, Thanks for taking time, I am interested to know what could be the reason, rather than how to solve it.

Comment: You might want to just use .Distinct rather than a group by where count > 1, because that's all that it's doing.  You add a fair bit of extra work by doing the full group by.  Edit: your final result will be total - numDistinct, not distinct.

Comment: The PLINQ version took ~2.4GB on my machine (64-bit OS, 12GB); the LINQ took ~1.5GB.  Take that 10M down to 8M and it should run on your machine.

Comment: FWIW, for a list of 10M Guids created with Guid.NewGuid, you could just echo "0 duplicates" (hard-coded) and be right 99.999...% of the time.

Comment: @murali - I don't understand the purpose of this question if you don't want to be provided a solution to the problem. I just realized that 160,000,000 bytes is 160MB not 16GB.  The reason the out of exception is obvious, using a PLINQ will take more resources, because the process is split between several threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably close to running out of memory on the regular Linq version as well, but using `AsParallel()` will add additional partitioning overhead to run in parallel and because of that you run over the limit.

When I tried your sample I had the same results at first, the non-parallel version would finish, but the PLinq version would run out of memory - doubling the Guid list size then caused both version to run out of memory. Also note 10 million Guids take about 152 MB space in memory

Also note that your current plinq and linq queries are only executed in your `Console.WriteLine()` - since Linq is lazy you have to force evaluation, i.e. using `ToList()` (or in your case `Count()`)

Comment: Since brokenGlass didn't mention it, the ramifications of that last line means that the timer is meaningless.  The count needs to be before the .Stop for it to mean anything.

Comment: If you're timing the cost of `AsParallel` vs not calling it, it means _something_. Though I would bet that wasn't the intent.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One way to at least dampen the problem is to not put all of the guids into a list, but rather to use an enumerable.

```
public IEnumerable<Guid> getGuids(int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        yield return Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

This has several advantages.  First, it's lazily loaded, so you'll fail in the middle of the processing rather than the declaration of the guids.  Second, you aren't holding onto all of the guids that fail the where clause; they can be removed from memory.  That means a LOT.  You'll only need to have one copy of each guid in memory, not two when you hit the where clause.